# Vim & ctags: Common ctags across all projects?

Tags: vim, ctags

I'm just getting acquainted with Vim's CTags functionality - and it's damn handy.

One issue I have, though, is regenerating common tags for each project.

For example - I do a fair bit of work in rails, and like to generate ctags for the whole rails framework with

```
alias rctags="ctags -R `bundle show rails`/../*"
```

The issue is I have to do this for every rails project I start up.

So, what's the standard way to automatically access a set of tags in any vim session - **ideally** only if the opened file satisfies a specific condition. (Eg rails ctags preloaded for .rb files, but not .py files)

Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `:help 'tags'`.

You could use, for example:

```
set tags+=~/.rails-tags
```

Which would cause `~/.rails-tags` to be searched for tags.

(also, on the topic of tags: it's probably useful to suffix the `tags` variable with `;/`. This means "search for a tags file in every parent of the working directory (ex, all the files `/foo/bar/tags`, `/foo/tags`, and `/tags` will be searched. For example, I use: `set tags=tags;/`).

Answer (score 2):

Why not to use plugin [Indexer](http://goo.gl/N2N1c) that was made especially for managing the ctags in Vim?

You can define your project in `~/.indexer_files` like this:

```
[my_rails_project]
/path/to/the/needed/directory
```

or even

```
[my_rails_project]
option:ctags_params = "--languages=Ruby"
/path/to/the/needed/directory
```

Then every time you opened Ruby file (i.e. `*.rb` or `*.ruby`) from the directory `/path/to/the/needed/directory` (with subdirs, of course), your tags will be generated automatically in background process, and when you save any file from this project, the tags will be updated automatically too (again, in the background).

So, you should not care about your tags generation, it just works.

For more information, see the article: [Vim: convenient code navigation for your projects](http://dmitryfrank.com/articles/vim_project_code_navigation), which explains the usage of Indexer + Vimprj thoroughly.